# How to make `execute` actions on semantic-ui modules with semantic-ui-ember?

Tags: ember.js, semantic-ui

I've written a [github issue](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-Ember/issues/169) 2 weeks ago on `semantic-ui-ember`'s repo but I got no answer yet. That's the reason why I'm reposting it here, hoping for more answers.

I'm trying to make a sample project out of the doc and can't get it working properly with all the docs I went through. I might be missing something really important. I'm actually able to get Semantic modules generated by ember but I get stuck when I try to interact with them and use actions on them.

I tried many different things but the closer I got was by following [this guide](http://semantic-org.github.io/Semantic-UI-Ember/#/modules/usage).

### Details on what I did. To see the actual error, please go to the end of my explanation.

1. I first installed ember: `npm install -g ember-cli`.
2. Then I created a new test project: `ember new testEmberSemantic`
3. Created the basic templates and a component for my future accordion test:

   ember generate template application
   ember generate template index
   ember generate component accordion-test
4. Then I install `Semantic-UI-Ember` and generate it:

   ember install semantic-ui-ember
   ember generate semantic-ui-ember
5. I then put the following in `templates/components/accordion-test.hbs`:

   ```
   {{yield}}
   {{#ui-accordion as |execute|}}
     <div class="title">
       Semantic UI
     </div>
     <div class="content">
       Be sure to check out <div class="ui button"
       onclick="{{action (execute 'open' 1)}}">the example</div>
     </div>
     <div class="title">
       Example
     </div>
     <div class="content">
       This is a great example!
     </div>
   {{/ui-accordion}}
   ```
6. I added a simple `{{accordion-test}}` in `templates/index.hbs` and `{{outlet}}` in `templates/application.hbs`.

### The error encountered.

7. Then, if I try to run `ember server` and load the webpage at `localhost:4200`, I have the following error in the console with nothing rendered on it.

   ```
   Assertion Failed: A helper named "execute" could not be found
   ```

If I try the same without the `execute` and `action` parts in `templates/components/accordion-test`, I get a normal page but, of course, without event handler on the button.

I kinda guessed, from what I read from the docs than it implicitly calls a method on the ui-accordion component in the base mixin that is supposed to call the method on the semantic component but it's not clearly said.

I even tried to add the following in `components/accordion-test`, just to make sure I wasn't required to create the "helper" myself.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend( {
  actions: {
    execute( command, argumentOne ) {
      $( '.ui.accordion' ).accordion( command, argumentOne );
    }
  }
} );
```

But that didn't help.
I think the main problem probably comes from my usage of `Semantic-UI-Ember` but this is the closest I can get to something working based on what I can find in the docs. Maybe that needs to be updated, to make sure a newcomer can get to a working example easily.

Also, I did all of this using `node v7.1.0` once and then tried it again (from scratch) with the `6.9.1` version and got the same results. So, it doesn't seem to be linked with the node version, here.

Thank you for your patience while reading this. :)

**PS**: This post might require a new tag called `semantic-ui-ember` as it uses this framework but I don't have the reputation to do so. Please, feel free to create it and tag this post to it. Thank you.